# Is it possible at all to install Ubuntu 10.04 on Windows 7 (64-bit) using its Virtual PC?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, virtual-machines, virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To Run Linux (Ubuntu) on Windows 7, is using Virtual PC one of the best ways?](https://serverfault.com/questions/144409/to-run-linux-ubuntu-on-windows-7-is-using-virtual-pc-one-of-the-best-ways)

It was said that Win 7's Virtual PC is not suitable for installing Ubuntu 10.04...  Is there any method at all that it will work?  The following is the scenario I ran into:

The first time Ubuntu 10.04 installation CD-R boots up, it asked for the Language, and "Install Ubuntu" and then the screen has vertical green bars and then the VPC just closed. The 2nd or 3rd time it booted up, there is no asking of Language or "Install Ubuntu" and just shut down the VPC, sometimes with vertical green bars. I even created another new hard drive and same thing happened. And created VPC 02, and same thing happened. Created VPC 03 with a fixed hard drive size of 60GB and same thing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is the same issue?

Virtual PC does not support 24bit color display -  [Virtual PC - Display Issue with Ubuntu Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/46360/virtual-pc-display-issue-with-ubuntu-server)